# Not all containers loading using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to dump a website (website link is given below in code) and all containers are not loading. In my case, price container is not dumping. See screenshots for more details. How to solve this?

[image]

[image]

In this case, container inside class "I6yQz" are not loading.

MyCode:

```
url = "https://gomechanic.in/gurgaon/car-battery-replacement/maruti-suzuki-versa/petrol"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

I need the following content shown in screenshot
[image]

Some thing like this:

data = {'CityName' : 'Gurgaon', 'CarName' : 'Versa-Petrol', 'serviceName' : 'Excide (55 Months Warranty)', 'Price' : '4299', 'ServicesOffered' : '['Free pickup & drop', 'Free Installation', 'Old Battery Price Included', 'Available at Doorstep']}

I have also got the API which is have all the information: https://gomechanic.app/api/v2/oauth/customer/get-services-details-by-category?car_id=249&city_id=1&category_id=-4&user_car_id=null (it will be visible by name 'get-services-details-by-category' in inspect element). The only problem is that I have to give carId and cityId instead of carName and cityName which I don't know which carId maps to what carName.

Comment: This page uses React/JavaScript to populate the DOM asynchronously, so BeautifulSoup is not going to see the information you're trying to scrape. The price information is retrieved from a REST API endpoint named `get-services-details-by-category`, the response of which is JSON and contains all the information you could ever want to scrape. Look up how to use Google Chrome's Dev Tools to log your browser's network traffic. Look for a request to the endpoint I mentioned, and then imitate that HTTP GET request using `requests`.

Comment: @PaulM. I tried that method you are saying. But there you will see that we have to give cityId and carId instead of cityName and carName which I don't know which Id correspond to which name. Do you have some how to do the mapping or directly get that API by loading this webpage only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment pointed out - this website dynamically loads some objects like prices via javascript.

When you connect to the page you can see a request in the background being made:

[image]

What you have to do is figure out how to replicate this request in your python code:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    # this website sues authroization for all requests
    'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJiNGJjM2NhZjVkMWVhOTlkYzk2YjQzM2NjYzQzMDI0ZTAyM2I0MGM2YjQ5ZjExN2JjMDk5OGY2MWU3ZDI1ZjM2MTU1YWU5ZDIxNjE2ZTc5NSIsInNjb3BlcyI6W10sInN1YiI6IjE2MzM5MzQwNjY5NCIsImV4cCI6MTYzNjUyNjA2Ny4wLCJhdWQiOiIzIiwibmJmIjoxNjMzOTM0MDY3LjAsImlhdCI6MTYzMzkzNDA2Ny4wfQ.QQI_iFpNgONAIp4bfoUbGDtnnYiiViEVsPQEK3ouYLjeyhMkEKyRclazuJ9i-ExQyqukFuqiAn4dw7drGUhRykJY6U67iSnbni0aXzzF9ZTEZrvMmqItHXjrdrxzYCqoKJAf2CYY-4hkO-NXIrTHZEnk-N_jhv30LHuK9A5I1qK8pajt4XIkC7grAn3gaMe3c6rX6Ko-AMZ801TVdACD4qIHb4o73a3vodEMvh4wjIcxRGUBGq4HBgAKxKLCcWaNz-z7XjvYrWhNJNB_iRjZ1YBN97Xk4CWxC0B4sSgA2dVsBWaKGW4ck8wvrHQyFRfFpPHux-6sCMqCC-e4okOhku3AasqPKwvUuJK4oov9tav4YsjfFevKkdsCZ1KmTehtvadoUXAHQcij0UqgMtzNPO-wKYoXwLc8yZGi_mfamAIX0izFOlFiuL26X8XUMP5HkuypUqDa3MLg91f-8oTMWfUjVYYsnjw7lwxKSl7KRKWWhuHwL6iDUjfB23qjEuq2h9JBVkoG71XpA9SrJbunWARYpQ48mc0LlYCXCbGkYIh9pOZba7JGMh7E15YyRla8qhU9pEkgWVYjzgYJaNkhrSNBaIdY56i_qlnTBpC00sqOnHRNVpYMb4gF3PPKalUMMJjbSqzEE2BNTFO5dGxGcz2cKP0smoVi_SK3XcKgPXc',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.15.2 Chrome/87.0.4280.144 Safari/537.36',
}

url = 'https://gomechanic.in/api/v1/priceList?city=gurgaon&brand=maruti-suzuki&service=car-battery-replacement'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

Which will result in:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "800 Petrol",
      "price": 3400,
      "savings": "25%"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "800 CNG",
      "price": 3400,
      "savings": "25%"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Alto Petrol",
      "price": 3400,
      "savings": "25%"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Alto CNG",
      "price": 3400,
      "savings": "25%"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Alto 800 Petrol",
      "price": 3400,
      "savings": "25%"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Alto 800 CNG",
      "price": 3400,
      "savings": "25%"
    }
  ]
}
```

This whole process is called reverse engineering and for a more in-depth introduction you can see my tutorial blog here: https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html

As for parameters that are used in these backend API requests - they are most likely in initial html document initial state json object. If you `view page source`  of the html page and `ctrl+f` parameter name like `city_id` you can see it's hidden deep in some json. You can either extract this whole JSON and parse it or use regular expressions like `re.findall('"city_id":(\d+)', html)[0]` to just get this one value.

Comment: I have tried out this method but if you will look at the content of API you are using, it doesn't have the data what webpage have. "get-services-details-by-category" is giving out the required data and here you will see we have to give carId and cityId instead of carName and cityName which I don't know which maps to what. So is there some method through which I can directly sget the API by loading webage only or some way in which I can map carId with carName? I want data of this website: https://gomechanic.in/gurgaon/car-battery-replacement/maruti-suzuki-versa/petrol .

Comment: @mukuldhiman ah so you don't know where to find parameters for this request. They have to come from somewhere for javascript to be able to form these requests. If you view page source of original html and ctrl+f `city_id` you can see that it's hidden deep in there in some initial state JSON. All you have to do is make request for html page -> extract city_id and other parameters -> make request to price API with these parameters. You can use regex to easily pick up these parameters.